# Access job parameter in ItemReader (spring-batch using grails)

Tags: java, grails, spring-batch

I am launching a job from my service and code look like

```
def jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder()
                .addDate('toDate',toDate)
                .addDate('fromDate',fromDate)
def jobEx = jobLauncher.run(billProcessJob,jobParameters.toJobParameters())
```

And it is executing successfully. But I need to access above job parameter in my Item Reader. My Item Reader looks like

```
class MyDomainMapper implements FieldSetMapper {
def mapLine(FieldSet fs) {
    if(!fs) {
         return null
    }
log.debug('Record:'+fs);//Printing the file record successfully

//Here I need to access my job parameter to map with some domain
}
}
```

Can any body tell me how I can achieve it?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a bean in your spring-batch context:

```
<bean id="executionContext" class="com.xxx.ExecutionContextImpl" scope="step" >
    <property name="toDate" value="#{jobParameters['toDate']}"  />
    <property name="fromDate" value="#{jobParameters['fromDate']}"  />
</bean>
```

And then inject the `executionContext` in your ItemReader to have acces to your job parameters variables.