# unable to passing parameters through job-parameters using spring batch at runtime

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-batch

**Code snippet:**

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(springConfig);

          JobLauncher jobLauncher = context.getBean("jobLauncher", JobLauncher.class);
          Job job = context.getBean("dadsdeviceJob",Job.class)         

          JobParameters jobParameters =
              new JobParametersBuilder().addString("input.file.name", "cvs/input/fxe_dadsDevice.dat").toJobParameters();

                       try {

                 JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);
```

**xml snippet:**

```
<bean id="dadsdeviceItemReader"  scope="step" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader">             
<property name="resource" value="classpath:#{jobParameters['input.file.name']}"/>
              <property name="lineMapper" ref="dadsdeviceLineMapper" />
              <property name="strict" value="false" />
       </bean>
```

```
Error: Input resource does not exist class path resource #{jobParameters['input.file.name']}.
```

can anyone please try to resolve it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13858593/access-job-parameter-in-itemreader-spring-batch-using-grails

Answer (score 0):

I am not seeing other config details but you can do like this

```
 JobLauncher jobLauncher = context.getBean("jobLauncher", JobLauncher.class);
     Job job = context.getBean("dadsdeviceJob",Job.class)       
    // get your bean and inject your resources like this before 
      FlatFileItemReader reader = (FlatFileItemReader) context.getBean("dadsdeviceItemReader");
       //       
     reader.setResource(new ClassPathResource(path));
     // or you can give FSR path also like this     
     reader.setResource(new FileSystemResource(path));
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, can you please suggest me, what will be the value need to be mentioned in beans propertyvalue

Comment: if you are following mentioned above approach then you don't need to set  bean resource property  in xml config just comment that line.                          <!--  <property name="resource" value="classpath:#{jobParameters['input.file.name']}"/>  -->